# Python deprecation warning about sum function

Tags: python, numpy, sum, deprecation-warning, generator-expression

I coded an algorithm and it worked properly till 2 weeks ago. I get this warning and I cannot understand why I get it. The warning is:

> "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Python/sezg_1_diffne.py:147:
>   DeprecationWarning: Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in
>   the future will give a different result. Use
>   np.sum(np.from_iter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.
>   obje_1=detmas.objVal+sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)"

A part of my code is:

```
obje_1=detmas.objVal+sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)
```

I tried something which I found in internet such as removing numpy and reinstall it. However these solutions did not work for my code. How I can solve it? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is there to solve? It is a warning and tells you that in the future your current solution (`np.sum`) may not work as expected and gives you the exact code to replace it with. You can either replace it with the suggested code now, or leave it for now - up to you.

Comment: It looks like you must have done `from numpy import sum`. Don't, otherwise you're overwritting the built-in `sum` method, which does work with generators

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However my code include only `import numpy as np` line. I solve with `obje_1=detmas.objVal+sum(hopen.values())*fixedCost` code. However I cannot solve for `for ind in range(0,sjt): tot_dis[ind]=sum(dist[unop[ind],ophu[stz]])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't import `sum` from `numpy`. Look for `from numpy import sum` or `from numpy import *` in your code and delete those lines. Otherwise, you will override the built-in `sum`. [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [built-in `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) are independent functions with different requirements.

The warning suggests while your code may work now, it may not work in the future. Notice you do in fact use a generator implicitly. These lines are equivalent:

```
sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)
sum((hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset))
```

In Python, extra parentheses are not required to explicitly denote a generator. Your error will disappear when you avoid importing `sum` from the NumPy library.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but hopen is a dictionary. So it did not work. I solved via values edit for all sums. However I did not solve how can i rewrite for ind in range(0,sjt):
                tot_dis[ind]=sum(dist[unop[ind],ophu[stz]]) constraint sets.

Comment: How about `np.sum([a[i] for i in range])`, just a new set of []?

Comment: @hpaulj, True, but I see not benefit of NumPy in this instance.. do you? It might be marginally more efficient to create a list (for small iterables) as iterating generators is expensive, but the performance difference is often marginal.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an alternative solution to the one by jpp. If you wish to keep the `from numpy import *` you can assign the built-in object to a different variable before importing numpy, as it is shown [here](http://I%20have%20found%20an%20alternative%20solution%20to%20the%20one%20by%20jpp.%20If%20you%20wish%20to%20keep%20the%20%60from%20numpy%20import%20*%60%20you%20can%20use%20the%20builtin%20object).

In your particular case you have two choices:

1. Import the built-in module:

   `import builtins` for Python 3, or `import __builtin__` for Python 2. And you call either `builtins.sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)` or `__builtin__.sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)`.
2. Assign the built-in sum to a different variable before importing numpy:

   `bltin_sum = sum`

   `from numpy import *`

   `bltin_sum(hopen[i]*fixedCost for i in Fset)`

I have already checked that the built-in sum behaves as expected for numpy arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to use `sum` instead of `np.sum`.  I ran into the same problem.  The warning went away after I switch to the built-in sum.

You don't have to do any special imports or assign anything.